# How can i configure shipping method - i need to cost calculated by weight related to zip code

Tags: shipping, zipcode

How can i configure shipping method - cost calculated  weight by zip code. how can i provide weight range and price for multiple zip code.

eg : Different zipcodes and weight range [image]

Is this right or wrong or may i do any changes... ??

Note : am using Webshopapps Matrix Rates extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The format of table rate shipping cost is as below. Each zipcode should have all the weight variations  and their cost.

[image: table rate shipping format]

You may endup having to do lot manual job of creating the sheet for 000s of zipcodes. Optionally you may consider an extentsion from webshopapps.com which give you the power to mention 'from' - 'to' zipcodes. thus minimising your work..

The file format with the extension will be like this [image: webshopapp ship matrix]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Co8kk.png                    as like this how can i add zipcode

Comment: and more one i need to add weight range for each zipcode of india

Comment: Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.